# mvc redirect does not work after I login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have a mvc controller called Auth, and a action called login, this look like this..

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> LogIn(LogInModel model)
    {
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
return View();
}

var user = await userManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);

if (user != null)
{
await SignIn(user);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.ReturnUrl))
{
 return Redirect(GetRedirectUrl(model.ReturnUrl));
}
else
{
//return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
return Redirect("../Home/Index");
}
}
else
{
return View();
}

// user authN failed
//ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid email or password");
//return View();
}
```

But I'm not redirected to my ../Home/Index. I stay on the same page even if I succed to login. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

What version of MVC are you using? I have secured pages with a login in the past using the below method and checking an enum that is part of asp.net Identitiy, as you can see the return URL is passed in to the method.

```
    private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

//
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

If you are using MVC 4 then you can use the [AllowAnonymous]

Comment: No reason, I tried that to but that does not redirect me to that page either.

Comment: have you tried setting a breakpoint in the Index view to see if it is even being hit? Have you set a breakpoint anywhere to check that the line of code is even being ran? I think you really use the RedirectToAction imo, is the ReturnUrl NullOrEmpty()?

Comment: The returnUrl is always empty even if it look like this.."auth/login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FIndex", and yes my code is ran but I cannot get to the redirect page ...

Comment: I got the RedirectUrl to work now by adding it as hidden field. But I'm not redirected. I think it has something to do with the fact that I secure all pages using filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());....

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, after method invocation changed to Ajax. Simply changed the response type to JavaScript and asked it execute a navigation since the results of the call is being handled inside a Javscript code block

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
switch (result)
{
  case SignInStatus.Success:

      var returnUrlJs = string.Format("location.href='{0}'", returnUrl);
      return new JavaScriptResult() { Script = returnUrlJs };
```